# VHDL parsing and counting some elements

Tags: vhdl

how can we find Depth(level) of the circuit contains (and, or, not gate) with 2 inputs without branch from VHDL netlist file

Comment: What sort of gate count are you trying to get?    Gate count can be square microns or nand gate equivalents in ASIC world, or in the FPGA world you can have LUTs (4, 5, 6).    Are you trying to get a realistic count or just an estimate?

Comment: What sort of code are you trying to process?   Just logic code or statemachines also?   For a statemachine, I suspect the best you can do is estimate gate count by counting the number of states and then apply a heuristic based on that and the complexity of the transitions.   For an ASIC we did in the early 90's, our guestimates  done this way were reasonably close to the final design - however in the ASIC, flip-flops were the dominating size item, so it was an easier problem than FPGAs.   For logic code, if you assume FPGA LUTs, you may be able to get something close.     Good luck.

Comment: Back to the "sort of code", is this a VHDL netlist that is already in gate format?   Then it becomes a very doable problem.   Homework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be blunt: you can't.

First: it requires a synthesis tool and those are very complex. Companies have spend many, many years (40+?) with teams of hundreds of people to develop those and that development is still ongoing.

Second: you need a target library, timing constraints and for silicon an area to get a wire load model. The library determines which gates are available and how fast they are. So you cant say *'this HDL code requires A gates'*. You can say *'this HDL code requires A gates in target library B to get the result out in C time in an area D'*.

The right approach is to chose a target, get the library for that, get the synthesis tool and then find out how big/fast the code is.

Comment: I suppose you could have the java run the compiler, and then have the java parse the logs files for the answer.

Comment: if it doesn't need to be Java: most of the synthesis tools come with dedicated tcl libraries that allow you to traverse the generated netlist and extract information. These tools are meant for static timing analysis, but should be able to do what you want. In worst case, call tcl from Java...